# Android not considering the complete GET parameters in the URL

Tags: java, android, get, connection-string

> What is the basic working scenario..?

If i try below `URL` from `web browser`, it works fine, sends a message.

[[http://49.50.67.32/smsapi/httpapi.jsp?username=myusername&password=mypassword&from=myfrom&to=919970316209&text=येथे+क्ल](http://49.50.67.32/smsapi/httpapi.jsp?username=myusername&password=mypassword&from=myfrom&to=919970316209&text=%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2)िक+करा+https://www.google.co.in/&coding=2][1]

** P.N : Do not try it, as i have changed the username and passwords..!!

> What is next..?

I want to make same GET request call, but from my android studio java project.

> What i have tried..?

As network operations are not allowed from main thread, i am implementing the same in a `Runnable Thread`. The code is as below :

```
String coding = "2";
String number = "919970316209";
String Text = "येथे+क्लिक+करा+https://www.google.co.in/";
String dummyURL = "http://49.50.67.32/smsapi/httpapi.jsp?username=myusername&password=mypassword&from=myfrom&to="+number+"&text="+Text+"&coding="+coding; 

URL url = new URL(dummyURL);
connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = null;
is = connection.getInputStream();

Log.d("SendViaGate : ", "OPENING : "+ url +" \n");
// FROM HERE ONWARD I GET THE RESPONSE FROM THIS REQUEST
```

> What is the problem..?

Android is not considering the `Unicode Text` as the part of the URL, So it breaks the URL, and opening connection with the partial URL.

**LOG_CAT**

```
04-07 18:34:41.253 7491-7584/com.versatilemarketers.apps.instafame D/SendViaGate :: Exception occurred in main thread.. 
04-07 18:34:41.254 7491-7584/com.versatilemarketers.apps.instafame W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://49.50.67.32/smsapi/httpapi.jsp?username=myusername&password=mypassword&from=myfrom&to=919970316209&text=येथे+क्लिक+करा+https://www.google.co.in/&coding=2
04-07 18:34:41.255 7491-7584/com.versatilemarketers.apps.instafame W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
        at com.versatilemarketers.apps.instafame.SendViaGate.run(SendViaGate.java:51)
```

In the above log-cat android is considering http://49.50.67.32/smsapi/httpapi.jsp?username=myusername&password=mypassword&from=myfrom&to=919970316209&text= 
 as a underlined URL, then येथे+क्लिक+करा+ as `text` and again https://www.google.co.in/&coding=2  as the second URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, it was because of the URL was not encoded before making the request, solved by :

```
URLEncoder.encode(Text, "UTF-8")
```

I got the reference from [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

The accepted answer of above thread, solved my issue too, Thanks a lot to the user @BalusC